# Xalan Java extensions 'Cannot find class' error on JRE 7

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I am running into a 'Cannot find class 'pkg.XSLTFunctions'. error on JRE 7 leading to a failures in compiling an XSL using Xalan. This worked perfectly in JRE 6. Here are some specifics of my application.

The application is a Win32 native EXE that loads the JVM using JNI, adds a JAR to the system classloader and runs a class in that JAR using JNI.  The Java class then pulls out an XSL from within the JAR and attempts to compile it.

The JAR also contains a Java class that is a Xalan Java extension and is specified in the XSL as so (shown below).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
    xmlns:util="xalan://testSoe.XSLTFunctions"                
    exclude-result-prefixes="p util xalan">
```

However, Xalan is unable to find this callback class and the compilation of the XSL fails. It errors out with

```
ExecGroup-0:err:ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'testSoe.XSLTFunctions'.'
```

This worked on JRE 6 and this issue is seen only on JRE 7. Any pointers as to what might be different between JRE 6 and 7 that could cause this behavior?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. The Xalan engine (internal to JRE) has the logic to look for a callback class in the boostrap classloader if 'SecurityManager' was set in the JVM, else it would look for it in the system classloader. The Win32 EXE I mentioned above is also our RMI server (once the JVM is loaded, etc). Its possible that JRE 7 sets the SecurityManager as part of setting up the RMI apparatus for that process to be the RMI Server. I am looking into the implications of turning it off but I have a workaround to proceed further! Took some debugging into the JDK source to figure this out!