# Error when try to call javascript function in xslt (Java JDK 8)

Tags: javascript, java, xslt, java-8, xalan

I’m trying to call javascript function in my XSL file.

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:jscript="http://www.url.com" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl jscript">
.
.
.
<html>
    <head>
    .
    .
    .
        <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="jscript">
            <![CDATA[
            function testFnc(){
                return "test";
                }
            }]]>
        </msxsl:script>
    </head>
    .
    .
    .
</html>
.
.
.
<xsl:value-of select="jscript:testFnc()"/>
```

In Java file, when I try to create  Transformer:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslUrl));
```

I get error:

> ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'www.url.com'.'>
>
> FATAL ERROR:  'Cannot find external method 'www.url.com.testFnc' (must
>   be public).'
>
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot find
>   external method 'www.url.com.testFnc' (must be public).

Without this code

```
<xsl:value-of select="jscript:testFnc()"/>
```

everything worked fine.

In Java 7 was similar problem with build-in Xalan: 
[Xalan Java extensions 'Cannot find class' error on JRE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171365/xalan-java-extensions-cannot-find-class-error-on-jre-7)

I was wondering is this problem is stil present in Java 8.

I also tried something like this:
http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#basic-pattern
[How to include a call to JavaScript within XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870682/how-to-include-a-call-to-javascript-within-xslt)

but results was the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The example you have shown relies on a proprietary extension to XSLT 1 introduced by Microsoft in its XSLT processors and I think also supported by some others (Altova, XmlPrime) to be compatible with Microsoft. As far as I know Xalan never supported that. As for the link, perhaps ask a second question with all the details on that. But in general these days in the Java world I would rather consider XSLT 3 with Saxon 9 and all the built-in XPath 3.1 function in addition to the `xsl:function` way to implement functions than to rely on Javascript.

Comment: As for the example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875807/252228, I think that will work with the interpretor version of Xalan from Apache, I think the built-in XSLT processor in Java 8 is XSLTC, the compiler version of Xalan, and that doesn't support the `xalan:component`/`xalan:script` extensions: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#java_ext. You should be able to call into Java, however.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Martin. I will consider, if I can switch to XSLT 3. But if I'm forced to stay on XSLT 1.0, is it possible to use javascript (not necessarily with Xalan processor )?

Comment: Well, yes, where supported, but you need to understand that it usually only means you have access to the core object and functions the used Javascript engine provides, like `Date`, `RegExp`. You don't have any access to APIs like window or document or anything you use with Javascript in the browser. So for XSLT 1 with XPath 1, where you have no date/dateTime data type and no support for regular expression based string functions, pure J(ava)Script offers some additional features. In XSLT/XPath 2 and later it usually doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. I was able to call Java function in xslt. I posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Honnen help I was able to use my own Java class in xslt code. You can find more information in documentation: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html#java_ext

xslt:

```
<xmlns:java_util="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/com.example.java.util" exclude-result-prefixes="java_util">
<!-- Java function call -->
<xsl:value-of select="java_util:DateUtil.formatDateTime(.)"/>
```

Java class:

```
package com.example.java.util;

public class DateUtil {
    public static String formatDateTime(String date){
    //implementation
}
}
```